# 301 redirects in Apache that preserve the referrer

Tags: apache-2.2, 301-redirect

Our web developers are using JavaScript redirects - first of all this does not work well for SEO and secondly, it does not preserve the http_referrer (therefore it does not show up in our web stats). So I'd like to get a 301 redirect in Apache, but I want to ensure the referrer will be passed along.

Does anyone know how to preserve the referrer with 301 redirects in Apache?

Will a 301 redirect with mod_rewrite preserve the referrer by default? Or do I need to use some custom code with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things in your apache VirtualHost config:

- Redirect 301 / http://www.askdavetaylor.com/
- RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.askdavetaylor.com/$1 [L,R=301]

But i think when you have to many rewrites you should write the rewrites to a .htaccess file.

Comment: Actually, just the opposite.  Have a look at this under the section "When not to use .htaccess":  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html.  If you have access to the Apache config files, it is better to use that instead of .htaccess files.  Overall performance is better when not using .htaccess files.

Comment: Will this preserve the referrer, so when the user lands on www.askdavetaylor.com, they use the right referrer?

Comment: Ignore my comment above. I have discovered the rewrite method above does preserve the referrer...